# AEM Solr - Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, aem, solr4

I want to configure a AEM Solr Search with full index, but the problems is, each time ie receive only 5 fiels (excertp, title, date, etc ).

Me i want :
- Title
- Link
- Content
- Score

Do youknow a good tutorial ? Some source ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go through the below link:

http://www.lucenetutorial.com/index.html

or 
Go to Below Link:

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/queries-and-indexing.html

Comment: Can you add some content from the links?